# mosquitto_sub: command not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, mosquitto, linux

I'm using a raspberry pi image that has the mosquitto broker installed. To troubleshoot, instruction was to run:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ mosquitto_sub -v -t "gateway/+/rx"
```

However that resulted in:

```
-bash: mosquitto_sub: command not found
```

Even though mosquitto was running:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo service mosquitto status
● mosquitto.service - LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mosquitto; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-09-30 21:43:51 UTC; 5h 14min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 347 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mosquitto start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mosquitto.service
           └─432 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Searching the problem did not produce easy to find answer.

Answer (score 12):

The solution is to install **mosquitto-clients** as well.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ apt-get install mosquitto-clients

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-ares2 libmosquitto1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-ares2 libmosquitto1 mosquitto-clients
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 178 kB of archives.
After this operation, 352 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

Now the `mosquitto_sub` command is usable.

Comment: Most of the examples on the web starts by installing and testing both broker and client on the same machine. I only wanted the broker on pi1 and client on pi2 and I had the same question because it did not work. If I understand we need the broker to subscribe if the client publish data. Why the command mosquitto_sub not usable with the broker? I might find one day.